# Angular JS Apply JS Plugin After Content Loaded By Route

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Good morning all ,
I have a problem with Angular JS

**Description:**
I'm using Bootstrap filestyle plugin http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/ 
when using

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="file"]').filestyle(); 
})
```

not works if content comes by Angular js Route 
I serched more I Founded code like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="file"]', function () {
        $('input[type="file"]').filestyle();
})
```

Works only when I Click the element

So i Need Event that fire after input[type="file"] loaded to DOM
or any idea to help me

thanks..

Comment: You need to wrap the bootstrap specific stuff in a angular directive that you add to your input type="file" or decorate the existing input directive, which may be more risky.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
    $('input[type="file"]').filestyle(); 
});
```

use this inside of your controller.

Comment: Thanks So much , Works Fine